# Getting run time error as "Must declare scalar variable @name"

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I am getting run time error as "Must declare scalar variable @name"

```
public partial class UserMainPage : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    string strConnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["FindConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    string str;
    SqlCommand com;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       label1.Text = Session["name"].ToString();
       string name = label1.Text;
       SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString);
       con.Open();
       str = "select balanceamount from wallet where username LIKE '%'+@name+'%'";

       com = new SqlCommand(str, con);
       SqlDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader();
       reader.Read();
       walletbalance.Text = reader["balanceamount"].ToString();
       reader.Close();
       con.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Just add `SqlParameter` for the query before `ExecuteReader`: `com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", name)`.

Comment: well you're not declaring @name for the SQL query so the error message is correct.

Comment: This is a code dump, not a question.

Answer (score 2):

Appreciate the try with parameterization instead for concatenated string queries. But You forgot to add the parameter to the command before executing them. And that causes the issues here. You can use the following code to add value to the specified parameter;

```
str = "select balanceamount from wallet where username LIKE @name";
com = new SqlCommand(str, con);
com.Parameters.AddWithValue(@name, "%" + name + "%"); 
SqlDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader();
// Process with reader
```

Answer (score 2):

In order to use parameters in `SqlCommand`, you should add them into `Parameters` dictionary ([see MSDN docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx)):

```
com.Parameters.Add("@name", "JohnSmith");
```

It also makes sense to move `%`s to the string value to avoid runtime concatenation:

```
com.Parameters.Add("@name", "%JohnSmith%");
```

And if you have a string variable in your code containing the name (you do have it), then:

```
string name = (string) Session["name"];
com.Parameters.Add("@name", $"%{name}%");
```